# ViewDoesNotExist at /news/ django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

```
Could not import photocomp.apps.news.views.news. View does not exist in module photocomp.apps.news.views.
```

it says i don't have a view at /news/ but here it is:

urls.py

```
url(r'^news/', include('photocomp.apps.news.urls')),
```

urls.py(for news)

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^submit/$', 'photocomp.apps.news.views.submit'),
url(r'^success/$', 'photocomp.apps.news.views.success'),
url(r'^$', 'photocomp.apps.news.views.news'),    
)
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'photocomp.apps.news',
)
```

and here is my view:

```
def news(request):
    news = News_Entry.objects.all().order_by('-publication')
    return render_to_response('news/news.html', {'news':news},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

what can cause this problem? I don't have it with the rest of the app.

Comment: do you have `__init__.py` in your news app? can you import your view from django shell? `python manage.py shell`?

Comment: Is it possible there's some sort of namespace issue, given that the upper-level module, the view function, objects within the view function, and potentially entities outside of the code included here are all called news?

Comment: thanks for the interest guys... found the problem

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

had a @login_required('/login') decorator instead of the @login_required(login_url='/login')